# I'm trying to make this random name generator in JS. The array is returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm trying to make a simple generator that takes some syllables from a user and randomly forms a made up word out of them.

I've managed to make a nice input system. It puts the syllables into a 2D array. I've tested it and it works.

When I try to alert random parts of the array it yells at me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var sounds = [[],[],[]];

        function makeName(x){
            alert(x[0][random(x[0].length)] + x[1][random(x[1].length)] + x[2][random(x[2].length)]); //Something is wrong here
        }

        function random(x){ //Random number between 0 and x-1
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*x); //The problem might be here too
        }

        var Count0 = 0;
        var Count1 = 0;
        var Count2 = 0;

        function add(type, fooNum) {

            //Create an input type
            var element = document.createElement("input");

            //Add to index of user supplied data
            if(fooNum == 1){
                Count0++;
                element.setAttribute("id","0:" + Count0);
            }else if(fooNum == 2){
                Count1++;
                element.setAttribute("id","1:" + Count1);
            }else if(fooNum == 3){
                Count2++;
                element.setAttribute("id","2:" + Count2);
            }else{
                alert("Somethin' went wrong, man!");
            }

            console.log(element.id);

            //Assign different attributes to the element.
            element.setAttribute("type", type);
            element.setAttribute("value", "");
            var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar"+fooNum);

            //Append the element in page (in <span>).
            foo.appendChild(element);

        }

        function generate(){ //Assign the inputs to a 2D array
            var counts = [Count0, Count1, Count2];
            hello=counts;
            for(k=0; k<=2; k++){
                for(i=0; i<=counts[k]; i++){
                        sounds[k][i] = document.getElementById(k + ":" + i).value;
                        alert(sounds[k][i]);
                }
                i = 0;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <FORM>

        <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value, 1)"/><INPUT type="text" name="element" id="0:0"/><span id="fooBar1">&nbsp;</span><P>
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value, 2)"/><INPUT type="text" name="element" id="1:0"/><span id="fooBar2">&nbsp;</span><P>
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value, 3)"/><INPUT type="text" name="element" id="2:0"/><span id="fooBar3">&nbsp;</span><P>

        <INPUT type="button" value="Generate" onclick="generate()"/><P>
        <INPUT type="button" value="Make Name" onclick="makeName()"/><P>
    </FORM>
</body>
```

My guess is that the problem lies within random() or makeName().

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `makeName` function takes argument `x`:

```
 function makeName(x) {
```

but you call it like this:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Make Name" onclick="makeName()"/>
```

that's why `x` is undefined in `makeName`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In your html you've called `makeName` function without any argument

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Make Name" onclick="makeName()"/><P>
```

but your function requires an argument

```
function makeName(x){
    alert(x[0][random(x[0].length)] + x[1][random(x[1].length)] + x[2][random(x[2].length)]);
}
```

So `x` is undefined in your `makeName` function.